# How to get the list item column values based on the html drop down and display in the alert box using Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, jquery, content-editor-web-part

I have a html dropdown list(team name) which contains three values A,B,C

I have a sharepoint 2010  List A which contains Team name and  Email.

List A

Teamname     Email

A        A@test.com

B        B@test.com

C             C@test.com

My requirment is 
if i select the html dropdown A, I need to display the A@test.com in alert box using javascript

if i select the html dropdown B, I need to display the B@test.com in alert box using javascript

if i select the html dropdown C, I need to display the A@test.com in alert box using javascript

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

These other answers tend to be too simple or way too complicated... ;)

This should do what you want, you just might need to change the `url` variable and the `select` parameters to conform with your environment -- but I took my best guess based on the information you provided. You could also remove the jQuery reference if your page already has it.

Here is a complete source for a content editor:

**Editted to remove excess html manipulation**

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option></option>
</select>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>    
<script>
(function() {
    // use ListData.svc with a REST API call to retrieve the data from your list
    var url = "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ListA?$select=Teamname,Email";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        //then update the select element with the results of your REST call
        var itemId,
            itemVal;
        // include the initial string value, like below, if you want an empty option to appear as the default
        var optionsArr = ["<option></option>"];
        var inputElement = $('#mySelect');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
            itemId = data.d.results[i].Teamname;
            itemVal = data.d.results[i].Email;
            //create the options that have a 'text' of the team name
            //and push their html strings into an array we'll use outside the loop
            optionsArr.push("<option value='" + itemVal + "'>" + itemId + "</option>");
        }
        // join the contents of the array and assign the result string to the html of the inputElement
        inputElement.html(optionsArr.join(""));
        // assign the change event to provide an alert of the selected option value
        inputElement.on('change', function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: I never used REST in SP2010, is the `/_api/lists/` endpoint not available in 2010?

Comment: Correct, no _api in 2010, it uses ListData.svc to provide the appropriate endpoints. There are some minor differences with how _api provides data in 2013 and this is naturally only list data, no webs or anything else... Here is the MSDN info specific to 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx

Comment: I like this approach, much simpler than the one I proposed. I just propose a simple change here: `inputElement.append("<option value='" + itemVal + "'>" + itemId + "</option>");
`

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you can use ECMAScript that is included to SharePoint. See [this post](http://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CFYQFjAE&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185007%28v=office.14%29.aspx&ei=nbXNUafqOcbGswbW3YGwBA&usg=AFQjCNHZVn79b2dLVLt_te_ywsCgsZ-4sg&sig2=wv3Fx0AHIPtSFAegT749lQ&bvm=bv.48572450,d.Yms) for more details.

In you case all that you need is to provide correct query and process request.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. But you have to use jQuery and SPServices in order to make it work. You can create a simple HTML Select (If the options will not increase) or just can populate using SPServices in case that you list keeps growing.

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown"></select>
```

JS:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.01/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
$(function () {
//Populates the dropdown list
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "{ListID}",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Team' /><FieldRef Name='Email' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
            var dropDown = "<option value='" + $(this).attr("ows_Team") + "'>" + $(this).attr("ows_Team") + "</option>";
            $("#dropdown").append(dropDown);
        }); //end of each() funtion
    } //end of completeFunc
}); //end of SPServices

$('#dropdown').on('change', function () {
    var teamDropDown = $(this).val();

    SPServicesCall("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Team' /><Value Type='Text'>" + teamDropDown + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>");
});


function SPServicesCall(CamlQuery) {
    var teamNamesArray = [];
    var emailsArray = [];
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "{ListID}",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Team' /><FieldRef Name='Email' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: CamlQuery,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                var teamNames = $(this).attr("ows_Team");
                var emails = $(this).attr("ows_Email");
                teamNamesArray.push(teamNames); //just in case you need it
                emailsArray.push(emails);//Emails
                alert(emailsArray);
            });
        } //end of  completefunc

    }); //end of SPServices
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">


// Execute the following JavaScript after the page has fully loaded, when it's ".ready"

$(document).ready(function(){


//Set alert based on drop down selection 

 $("select[title='YourColumnNameHere]").change(function() {

  if ($("select[title='YourColumnNameHere']").val() == "Email A Selection Value") { 

  alert('A@test.com');

  } if($("select[title='YourColumnNameHere2]").val() == "Email B Selection Value"){ 

  alert('B@test.com');

  } if($("select[title='YourColumnNameHere3]").val() == "Email C Selection Value"){ 

  alert('C@test.com');

  }
 });
```

Comment: I don't think this would work, you are assuming that the data has been retrieved from SharePoint already.