# Response field with an image depending of field selected SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form

I have a list who have a select field with numbers 1,2 or 3 to create a field on a list, that I want to do is to load another field who respond this one.

For example, if I select 1 display me into another field an image.

How can I do that using the only SharePoint online without a designer? is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but I think you can create three content types (let's say 1, 2 and 3) and add the fields you want to appropriate content type.  For example Content Type 1 will have Title field only but Content Type 2 will have Title and Image.

**Content Type 1**

[image]

**Content Type 2**

[image]

In case this is not what you were looking for, have a look at [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field) but you will need to use JavaScript/JQuery

Comment: Imagine I have a select list, depending of selected value another field load with an image depending of selected value. I don´t have an idea of how to do that

Comment: You mean a list with Toys and when I select a particular toy it should show a image of that toy?

Comment: Exactly, that´s that I want

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do this out of the box you will need to do it through javascript

Comment: Do you have some example about it? I search in google but didn´t found any

Comment: This is similar but not exactly what you are looking for but should give you some idea: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71666/how-to-get-the-list-item-column-values-based-on-the-html-drop-down-and-display-i

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to take the data entered by a user when creating/editing an item, and use it to display something different in a view, etc.. you'll want to look at utilizing JSLink.

Here's an example where a status indicator image is shown on a view, based on the data entered for that field.

http://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/using-a-js-link-override-in-sharepoint-online

Hope that helps - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the modern experience, then you can do something like that:

1.Create a Pictures library and upload some images

[image: ,]

2. In your list add a lookup field named "Picture" pointing to the Pictures library and in this column show "Title".
3. In the "Column Formatting" field enter the below json and replace the value of "src" attribute with your address:

   {
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "img",
   "attributes": {
   "src": "='https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/Pictures/'+ @currentField.lookupValue + '.png'"
   },
   "style": {
   "width": "120px"
   }
   }
4. Save the form and add the "Picture" field to a view in your list
5. Add some items to your list and be sure to choose something in the "Picture" field.
6. You should get something like that:

[image]

7. You can also format the column directly in the list view:

[image]