# Inject javascript to a list without using third programs -Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript

I have a simple form like this:

[image]

I want to know, how can I import some javascript function to that list?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to customize the view, perform an action, etc.?

Comment: @theChrisKent I want to perform an action like a select response. If I select on value in a select list then show me an image

Comment: @Ledwing you need Preview item pictures?

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov yes

Comment: Duplicate: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224133/response-field-with-an-image-depending-of-field-selected-sharepoint-online/224140?noredirect=1#comment240964_224140

Comment: This is not dupplicate, Im asking how can I inject javascript to a list

Comment: You can use JSLink to add custom Javascript to your list rendering. It usually uses CSR (Client Side Rendering) to customize the rendering of standard list views and forms. Random example here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37203.sharepoint-online-customize-list-view-web-part-using-jslink.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 0):

You can add a 'script editor webpart' to this view/page (only in classic view):

Gear icon -> Edit page -> add a webpart -> choose 'Script editor' -> edit the content of the webpart